# Clojure: Escaping unicode `\U` in JSON encoding

Tags: json, unicode, clojure, elm

## Postamble for future readers

- Elm allows literal `C:\Users\myuser` in strings
- This is consistent with the JSON spec
- My problem was unrelated to this, but several layers of escaping convoluted the problem. Future lesson: fully producing a minimal working example would have found the error!

## Original question

I have a Clojure backend that talks to an Elm frontend. I hit a bump when decoding JSON values in Elm.

`\U` below means the literal characters backslash and U, as if read from a text file. `"\\U"` is the same string as input in Clojure and Elm source (`\` must be escaped). Note enclosing `""`.

### Problem: encoding `\U`

The literal string `\U`, escaped `"\\U"` is not accepted by the Elm string decoder.

[A blog post](http://arpan-khandelwal-tech.blogspot.no/2008/08/this-article-is-related-to-escaping-of.html) suggests that to obtain the literal string `\U`, this should be encoded in source code as `"\\\\U"`, "escaping the unicode escape".

The literal string I want to send to the client is `C:\Users\myuser`. I prefer to send valid JSON from the server to the client.

### Clojure standard library behavior

`clojure.data.json` does not do anything special for strings containing the literal `\U`. The example below shows that `\U` and `\m` are threated equally, the backslash is escaped, and the following character ignored.

```
project.core> (clojure.data.json/write-str "C:\\Users\\myuser")
"\"C:\\\\Users\\\\myuser\""
```

### Manual workaround

Temporary workaround is manually escaping the strings I need:

```
(defn escape-backslash-u [s]
  (clojure.string/replace s "\\U" "\\\\U"))
```

### Concrete questions

- Is `clojure.data.json/write-str` behaving correctly? As I understand the documentation, output should be valid unicode.
- Are other JSON libraries behaving similarly?
- Is Elm's [Json.Decode](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode) behaving correctly by rejecting the literal string `\U`?

### Solution progress

- A friendly Clojurians Slack user pointed to the JSON standard specification, specifically sections [7. Strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7) and [8.2. Unicode characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-8.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be on the wrong track here.

The string you gave as an example, `"C:\\Users\\myuser"` is completely unproblematic, it does not contain any Unicode escape sequences. It is a string containing the ASCII characters ‘C’, ‘:’, ‘\’, ‘U’, and so on. The backslash is the escape character in Clojure strings so it needs to be escaped itself to represent a literal backslash.

In any case the string `"C:\\Users\\myuser"` can be serialized with `(clojure.data.json/write-str "C:\\Users\\myuser")`, and, as you know, this gives `"\"C:\\\\Users\\\\myuser\""`. All of this seems perfectly straightforward and sound.

Printing `"\"C:\\\\Users\\\\myuser\""` results in the original string `"C:\\Users\\myuser"` being printed. That string is accepted as valid by [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/), again as expected.

Comment: I created a [minimal example](https://ellie-app.com/3sgzWZyGTy8a1/2) to produce what I thought was happening, and I couldn't reproduce what I thought was wrong. I think I made a mistake with my test data. Thanks!

Comment: Update: found the error, was somewhere else. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I understood it as `Elm` beeing unable to decode `\"C:\\\\User...` to `"C:\\User...` because it interprets `\u` as start for an escape sequence.

I tried elm [here](http://elm-lang.org/examples/hello-html) with the following code:

```
import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "\"c:\\\\user\\\\foo\"" // from clojure.data.json/write-str
```

which in turn compiles/runs to

```
"c:\\user\\foo"
```

which looks fine to me.

Are you sure there is nothing else going on (middleware, transport) ?

Comment: "I understood it as Elm beeing unable to decode \"C:\\\\User... to "C:\\User... because it interprets \u as start for an escape sequence." - yes, that's what I think. My issue is not with normal Elm string handling, as your example shows, but with the [JSON string decoder](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#string) that you use to build JSON parsers. I'll try get a minimal example up.

Comment: I created a [minimal example](https://ellie-app.com/3sgzWZyGTy8a1/2) to produce what I thought was happening, and I couldn't reproduce what I thought was wrong. I think I made a mistake with my test data. Thanks!

Comment: Update: found the error, was somewhere else. Thanks again.